Should [tag:ecdsa] be a separate tag from [tag:dsa]?
In a recent question, I tried to edit in an ecdsa tag, but it's shown to be aliased to dsa.
I don't quite agree with this, as DSA is pretty much obsolete (due to it being poorly specified and poorly revised during its life time), and that ECDSA and DSA are in fact two separated algorithm with only nominal relationship.
What do you think?

The decision to go in the other direction can be found here. The idea is to combine the [tag:dsa] and [tag:elliptic-curves] tags. The idea was to have both map to DSA as the questions would generally work for both ECDSA and DSA apparently.
